# Logging configurations for xml in log4j.xml (jboss-log4j.xml)

Tags: xml, logging, log4j

I want to use RollingFileAppender with size and time restriction. Therefore I wrote the following appender for my xml-configuration.

```
<appender name="MyLogger" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/> 
      <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/mylog_01.log"/>  
      <param name="Append" value="true"/> 
      <param name="MaxFileSize" value="100KB"/> 
      <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/> 
      <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <param name="FileNamePattern" value="mylog_01_%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm}.log" />
      </rollingPolicy>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %5p %t (%F[%M]\:%L) - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
</appender>
```

Although I have compared my appender with lots of recent examples, I couldn't find my mistake(s). My apperder produces the first log-data with the name "mylog_01.log". I'm expecting to have the log-datas with following respectively, such as

```
mylog_01_2013-09-09_12-33.log
mylog_01_2013-09-09_12-34.log
mylog_01_2013-09-09_12-35.log
mylog_01_2013-09-09_12-36.log ...
```

But the appender produces them with default pattern, such as `ylog_01.log.1`, `mylog_01.log.2`, `mylog_01.log.3` ...

Could you help me please to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up your `RollingFileAppender`s.  The `org.jboss.logging.appender.RollingFileAppender` extends the Log4J built-in `org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender`, but the `<rollingPolicy>` configuration element is a feature of `org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender`, an unrelated class from [log4j-extras](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/).

The standard Log4J RollingFileAppender only does sequential numbering of backup files, not time-based naming.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understood my mistakes partially, but I have not got any solution for the problem anymore. Do you have any recommendation for time-based naming? How can I solve this problem or correct my solution?

Comment: @neopard you could include the log4j-extras library in your application and then use `org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender` instead of `org.jboss.logging.appender.RollingFileAppender`.  As far as I can tell the only thing the jboss appender does that the log4j-extras one doesn't is to automatically create the directory to contain the log file, if that directory doesn't already exist.  If you make sure to create the directory yourself before starting your app then it'll work fine.

Comment: I dropped `apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar` in `JBOSS_HOME/lib` and I got: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender`
Where should I put this file?